# I have to update a particular field without affecting the other field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588899367e36402204026a44"),
    "age" : 21,
    "fullname" : {
        "firstname" : "kathir"
        "lastname" : "rajan"
    },      
    "mark" : [
        90,
        32,
        56,
        12,
        75
    ]
}
```

I need to update `"firstname"` field that precent within the "fullname"`

I tried this

```
db.autos.update(
    { "age": 21 },
    { $set: {" fullname": { "lastname": "raja" } } }
)
```

but this query deletes the `"firstname"` field and produces the following output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588899367e36402204026a44"),
    "age" : 21,
    "fullname" : {
        "lastname" : "raja"
    },
    "mark" : [
        90,
        32,
        56,
        12,
        75
    ]
}
```

Comment: `db.autos.update({"age":21},{$set:{"fullname.lastname":"raja"}})`

Comment: Note the dot between `fullname` and `lastname`

Comment: @chridam I wish I had a gold badge :(

Comment: @Styvane That would be very handy as a lot of dupes keep popping up now and then and that needs some cleanup. You have 912 points, not far to go to get that gold, you only need 78 more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot syntax

```
db.autos.update({ "age": 21 },{ $set: { "fullname.lastname": "raja" } })
```